# 3-letter arrangement for "silly" - Permutations homework

Tags: permutations

We a homework question that asks us to find the 3 letter arrangement of the word "Silly".
Here is the exact question.

> How many three-letter arrangements are there of the letters taken
>   from the word SILLY?

What I did was do $5P3/2!$ and I ended up getting 30. The answer is 33. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have just realized, should I be adding back 3 because of a permutation that does have the LL's in it?

Comment: When you choose three letters out of 5, one of the possibilities is S,I,L which has no repetitions. So dividing by $2!$ is wrong.

Comment: What should be the correct step then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this small problem the easy way is to note first that there are $4\cdot3\cdot2=24$ ways to pick three **different** letters and permute them. Then observe that there are $3$ ways to pair LL with one of the other letters, and $3$ ways to place that odd letter relative to the two L’s, so there are $3\cdot3=9$ more $3$-letter arrangements that include both L’s, for a total of $24+9=33$ arrangements.